# Cannot edit search settings in Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, feedback

I am unable to edit my search settings in Careers 2.0.

I responded to a message that I was not currently looking for a job and it automatically changed my search settings to "blocked" from employer view. I am trying to mark myself as "passive", so that I still show in search results.

When I click "edit search settings", it just refreshes the page and does not give me the ability to switch my settings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I could repro'd on FF4

Comment: Yup - looks like it's a bug... We'll fix asap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the changes I made to the completeness score a couple days ago.  It will be fixed shortly, but for now you can edit your search status by clicking on the edit button to the right of the `Job search status` listing on the edit view.  It should either be the second or third edit link from the top depending on if you have top percentiles or not.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Worked like a charm!